# Why won't the top three strings change pitch

Tags: guitar, tuning, strings

I ended up breaking the high E string because using an electronic tuner and my ear, it clearly wasn't changing at all. Kept tightening the string and eventually it broke behind the nut. To look into this more I flattened the G and B strings and was wondering why the pitch wasn't changing. I looked behind the nut and see the strings are dangling while the portion of the strings that are on the fret board are as tight as before. The only thing that makes sense to me is that there is a problem with the nut, but I don't see how looking at it would help unless I took it apart...

The guitar  is an Ibanez with a floyd rose.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a locking nut?  It's possible for strings to stick regular nut slots, but I can't imagine it sticking THAT much.

Comment: @Edward I am not sure, there are three little pieces above the nut (that were loose and then the luthier fitted and tightened them so that they don't move at all). Also, the actual nut I guess has grooves where the strings go through too. He did a great job overall, and I have tuned them recently, but this time it just didn't work out I guess. I can't add photos at the moment due to email issues from my phone.

Comment: Do you know the make and model of the guitar? Does it have a vibrato bridge? (Whammy bar)

Comment: It is an Ibanez with a floyd rose

Comment: when I started to read your post, I thought about the classic: "weird, the pitch hasn't changed, let me keep tightening the wrong string until it breaks" :) I have a guitar with a floyd rose, but it's tuned a semitone lower and each time someone holds it, they instantly try to turn the tuners and I have to rush telling them 'no no no, don't!'

Comment: Does your guitar look like this ? https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100161/electric-guitar-intonation-flat-above-12th-fret-no-luck-with-usual-methods

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Yes

Comment: I've edited it into your question. You can re-edit if you wish.

Comment: Looking at the picture, what did you think the screws were for?

Comment: @Tim To lock in those pieces into the nut. That doesn't necessarily mean the strings will be locked in too, but apparently they were after getting the guitar set up (but they weren't before).

Comment: @DerekLuna - when I set up a guitar, all the strings (not just half of them) will be locked. All or nothing. There's no point in locking half which actually may have been the case here.. But why, who knows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The instrument in question is an Ibanez with a Floyd Rose tremolo system, which allows you to provide vibrato without changing tuning.

They have a locking nut, with three hex bolts holding the string in position. Once the nut is tightened, the tension between the nut and tuner is immaterial. It should hold tuning even when the string is broken.

For *most* Floyd Rose systems, there are fine tuners on the bridge that allow you to tune up without opening the locking nut.

**ETA:** [Here is the site for Floyd Rose, which should have catalog pages which show both the versions with and without fine-tuners, as well as support pages which help with the care and feeding of your guitar bridge.](https://floydrose.com/) Ibanez uses a variant, the [Edge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibanez_Edge). I'm not sure the differences, both legal and technical, but they should be similar enough to get you through restringing and tuning.

Comment: The bridge is pretty far away in the photo, but you can just about make out the knobs on the fine tuners I think.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt The picture in the question is not actually the asker's guitar, just one that looks similar.  Though it may be useful to add a picture pointing out the fine tuners in this answer, in case someone does have the same type of Floyd Rose system.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt the picture has been added to the question, not my answer, so this conversation might best go there.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to tune the guitar using the machine heads, you need to loosen the three screws at the nut. They're holding the strings tight, which is why what you did happened. The top string you simply tightened from the nut to the machine head - no wonder it broke where it did. The other two, you loosened, but that only loosened them from machine head to nut. So they stayed at the same pitch.

Loosen off the nut, don't take off the bar though, just enough for the strings to slide through. Tune the guitar as normal then. There are usually some fine tuners by the bridge. Try to get those at about their central point. Tune, tighten the locking nut.

Don't touch the machine heads again, but any fine tuning can be done at the bridge end.